# How to have a discord bot send a message word by word in the same line?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have something like this:

```
    actquestion = ['hello', 'world!']
    split = actquestion.split()
    for z in range(0, len(split)):  
      await asyncio.sleep(.65)
      message = await message.channel.send(split[z])
```

But that just sends the message line by line, not in the same line.
So the bot sends something like this:

hello
world!

Instead of:

hello world!

How can I have it do the second one?

Comment: You mean, word by word with a delay between each word?  I'm not sure discord supports that.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean

Comment: You could edit the message continuously, although do be careful for rate limits.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs how would I do that?